# Align the items in a div using Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I am new to front end. The question I am asking may be very basic.
Here I am using ReactJS.

[image]

So actually, I am trying to do this. So, what I have tried is

```
<div className="row">
    <div className="col-10" style={selectques}>
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-4">
                <span className="align-middle">1</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="col-2">
    </div>
</div >
```

Here, I tried using the select but still it was not working properly. Can anyone suggest me how to do this? And align it the way it is? Any hint will be helpful.

Comment: If you want I can help you in bootstrap. without react js

Comment: Please post all of the relevant code.

Comment: Yes, I want to do the bootstrap

Comment: You want vertically align all items in row?

Comment: yes I want to align all items in a row

Answer (score 1):

By default [Bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/) uses flexbox layout. It means that rows (tags with class `.row`) have `display: flex`.

Basically it means you have to align items along the cross axis on the current line. To do that you should use [align-items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items). Bootstrap already has [helper classes for it](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#vertical-alignment). So you just need to add appropriate one to your `.row`:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row align-items-center" style="background-color: #f7f7f7;">
  <div class="col">normal text</div>
  <div class="col-auto"> <input type="text"> </div>
  <div class="col"><h1>Big text</h1></div>
  <div class="col">
    <select>
      <option value="1" selected>Option 1</option>
      <option value="1">Option 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, what is happening , when I add a select element then it is not taking that element.

Comment: @GaneshKaspate I updated code snippet with `select` and it's aligned properly